# Horizontal scrollbar control for child div outside parent div/ floating div control

Tags: jquery, css, html

Developed a replica of the question:

http://jsfiddle.net/m8pDd/

If you refer to the fiddle it has two div's inside a parent div, when parent div is overflowed to show the vertical scrollbar the right inner div's horizontal scrollbar goes inside the overflowed vertically and the horizontal scrollbar is unavialable for the person to use.

How can we achieve the horizontal scrollbar of inner div to be accessed even if the data is more; seems to me like floating or creating a replica of the scrollbar outside the parent div??

Any ideas??

Code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="left-order-panel">
        <table id="edit-left">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>h1</th>
                <th>h2</th>
                <th>h3</th>
                <th>h4</th>
                <th>h5</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>h1</td>
                <td>h2</td>
                <td>h3</td>
                <td>h4</td>
                <td>h5</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <table id="data-left">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>h1</th>
                <th>h2</th>
                <th>h3</th>
                <th>h4</th>
                <th>h5</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>v1</tr>
                <tr>v2</tr>
                <tr>V3</tr>
                <tr>v4</tr>
                <tr>V5</tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="right-order-panel">
        <div id="right-order-inner">
         <table id="order-right">
             <thead>
                <tr style="height: 26px;">
                    <th data-lang="dashboard.order-projection" colspan="10">Order Projection</th>
                </tr>
                 <tr style="height: 26px;">
                     <th colspan="4"> 2013 </th>
                     <th colspan="4"> 2014 </th>
                 </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr style="height: 26px;">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                       <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr style="height: 26px;">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                     <td>4</td>
                     <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr style="height: 26px;">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                     <td>4</td>
                     <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 26px;">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
         </table>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Post your code in jsfiddle,it helps very much to analyse.

Comment: I can try, it is a big concept code in application view.. let me try in some blue print way... @Sharath was it clear by sentences above??

Comment: Edited my question with code and proper explanantion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with some JQuery.

Just include the library:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

See JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V4T4V/

Using the scroll function you can detect when wrapper1 is being scrolled and then move wrapper2.

```
$(function(){
    $(".wrapper1").scroll(function(){
        $(".wrapper2")
            .scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
    });
    $(".wrapper2").scroll(function(){
        $(".wrapper1")
            .scrollLeft($(".wrapper2").scrollLeft());
    });
});
```

You can then place this bar outside the div, at the top etc.

Simply place this where you want the scrollbar (note the wrapper's css must be the same width):

```
<div class="wrapper1">
    <div class="div1">
    </div>
</div>
```

You could then go on to float the scroller inside your parent div with some css positioning.

Comment: Please refer to the fiddle, i maynot be clear for my scenario

Comment: On doubt buddy, i have some hidden items in the inner div, which allow the inner scrollbar to adjust the width and the scroll becomes wider but the replica scrollbar is same as before. how can we handle that??

Comment: you just need to change the width of "div1" in the css to match that width.

Comment: I am getting in trouble with inner div and outside scroll as i have hidden items which when shown in inner div, the outer scrollbar is not getting updated as inner div...???

Comment: @SimonStation: can we control the scrollbar to be replicated as same as the width of the inner div if it is changed??

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    <p>some text..</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
    height: 100px; width: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.inner {
    width: 200px; height: 100px;
}
p {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Essentially I've added an `inner` container with a specified `height` and `width`. Now the `overflow` occurs on the `outer` container and you can space the bars accordingly.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xareyo/Mbs4D/)